# My phone suddenly start typing "####"

Tags: screen

I have a Redmi 9 on Android 13. It suddenly started typing "#####..." nonstop, then sometimes opened an app or multiple windows.

My approach:

1. Press power button
2. Clear trash
3. Reboot
4. Factory reset
5. Changed screen protector

I am still facing this problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean.  Text has to be on a text input box.  It can't appear on the blank screen, unless it hasnt finished booting up.  What did you install last?

Comment: I have a feeling either a ghost touch or a broken digitizer. Turn on Developer options then Show touches, and check whether there are random touches even if you don't touch the screen.